# How to perform p4 submit operation ONLY on files which has diff?

Tags: submit, perforce

I would like to know if there's a built-in function in P4 or a way to basically only allow the p4 submit to commit ONLY when the file has a diff. Let said I have rev 1, and I want to update the file with rev 2. But I should be only allow to make this change if rev 2 is actually diff from rev 1.

I checked P4 [Manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/submit.html) on "p4 submit" , but I don't see much about this type of scenarios. The P4V GUI has one of these options, but how do we get this accomplish in command-line?  Thanks.

```
p4 submit  -d "Update new drop $now" file.txt
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few options.

1. Add either the `-f revertunchanged` or `-f leaveunchanged` options on the `p4 submit` command ([p4 help submit](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/submit.html)).
2. Perform a `p4 revert -a` command *before* submitting ([p4 help revert](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/revert.html#1040665))
3. Change the `SubmitOptions` on your client (a.k.a your workspace) so that it **will always** revert unchanged files before submitting ([p4 help client](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/client.html#1040665)).

P4V can be considered a wrapper of the `p4` command line, i.e. it performs the exact same commands.

Tips:

- If you want to see what you commands P4V is performing, go to your preferences and change the log settings to output more detail.
- Did you notice the way I formatted the help links? If you type that (e.g. `p4 help submit`) into your command prompt / terminal, it will display the help for that command. If you want to see what other commands are available type `p4 help commands`.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `-f reventunchanged` or `-f leaveunchanged` options.  See [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/submit.html) under the options section for various options that are available to you.  The former will automatically revert the unchanged files, the latter will leave them alone.  In both cases changed files will be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'p4 submit -f revertunchanged -d "my description" file.txt' might be useful to you.